# javascript xml nodevalue not working

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I'm trying to extract an element called lastupdated from a parent node called episode:
data -> Episode -> lastupdate

if I wrote:

```
episodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Episode");
console.log(episodeList[1].getElementsByTagName("lastupdated")[0])
```

it returns me the item zero of a list of length 1 but with the lastupdated tags

If I wrote:

```
console.log(episodeList[1].getElementsByTagName("lastupdated")[0].nodeValue)
```

it returns null!
why is that?

responding:
textValue returns null

xml part:
TextContent also return null. here goes the xml:

```
<Data>
<Series>
<id>75760</id>
<Actors>
|Josh Radnor|Cobie Smulders|Neil Patrick Harris|Jason Segel|Alyson Hannigan|Bob Saget|
</Actors>
<Airs_DayOfWeek>Monday</Airs_DayOfWeek>
<Airs_Time>8:00 PM</Airs_Time>
<ContentRating>TV-PG</ContentRating>
<FirstAired>2005-09-19</FirstAired>
<Genre>|Comedy|</Genre>
<IMDB_ID>tt0460649</IMDB_ID>
<Language>en</Language>
<Network>CBS</Network>
<NetworkID/>
<Overview>
How I Met Your Mother is a comedy about Ted and how he fell in love. It all started when Ted's best friend, Marshall, dropped the bombshell that he was going to propose to his longtime girlfriend, Lily, a kindergarten teacher. At that moment, Ted realized that he had better get a move on if he, too, hopes to find true love. Helping him in his quest is his friend Barney, a confirmed bachelor with endless, sometimes outrageous opinions, a penchant for suits and a foolproof way to meet women. When Ted meets Robin, he's sure it's love at first sight, but destiny has something else in store.
</Overview>
<Rating>9.2</Rating>
<RatingCount>381</RatingCount>
<Runtime>30</Runtime>
<SeriesID>33700</SeriesID>
<SeriesName>How I Met Your Mother</SeriesName>
<Status>Continuing</Status>
<added/>
<addedBy/>
<banner>graphical/75760-g25.jpg</banner>
<fanart>fanart/original/75760-45.jpg</fanart>
<lastupdated>1333146863</lastupdated>
<poster>posters/75760-12.jpg</poster>
<zap2it_id>EP00753796</zap2it_id>
</Series>
<Episode>
<id>1159571</id>
<Combined_episodenumber>1</Combined_episodenumber>
<Combined_season>0</Combined_season>
<DVD_chapter/>
<DVD_discid/>
<DVD_episodenumber/>
<DVD_season/>
<Director/>
<EpImgFlag>1</EpImgFlag>
<EpisodeName>Robin Sparkles Music Video - Let's Go to the Mall</EpisodeName>
<EpisodeNumber>1</EpisodeNumber>
<FirstAired>2006-11-20</FirstAired>
<GuestStars/>
<IMDB_ID/>
<Language>en</Language>
<Overview/>
<ProductionCode/>
<Rating>4.0</Rating>
<RatingCount>1</RatingCount>
<SeasonNumber>0</SeasonNumber>
<Writer/>
<absolute_number/>
<airsafter_season/>
<airsbefore_episode>10</airsbefore_episode>
<airsbefore_season>2</airsbefore_season>
<filename>episodes/75760/1159571.jpg</filename>
<lastupdated>1275339740</lastupdated>
<seasonid>23219</seasonid>
<seriesid>75760</seriesid>
</Episode>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `nodeValue` instead of `nodevalue`. Javascript is case sensitive and there is no `nodevalue` property of [DOM Node](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_node.asp).

**UPDATE:** Also you need to use `textContent` if you want text value within xml node.
For more information look [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) and [nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue) references.

Comment: @MarcoMartins Can you provide that part of XML, you are working on?

Comment: @MarcoMartins Maybe you need to use `textContent` instead of `nodeValue`?

Comment: just updated the first post with the xml, textContent doesn't help

Comment: @MarcoMartins This `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Episode")[0].getElementsByTagName("lastupdated")[0].textContent` works for me.

Comment: try like this, to see if it works for you:
var episodeList = new Array();
  episodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Episode");
  var episodeUpdatedTime = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i < episodeList.length; i++){
   episodeUpdatedTime.push(episodeList[i].getElementsByTagName("lastupdated"))
  }
  console.log(episodeList[1].getElementsByTagName("lastupdated")[0]);
  console.log(episodeUpdatedTime[0].parseInt);

Comment: DOM Node does not have `parseInt` property or method. If you want to parse to int then you should call `parseInt(episodeUpdatedTime[0].textContent)`. Was that your problem?

Comment: @MarcoMartins Also push `getElementsByTagName("lastupdated")[0]` not `getElementsByTagName("lastupdated")` into array.

Comment: sorry parseInt was just a test :p

Comment: The console log still prints with the lastupdated tags, if I try nodeValue it says null, but it works with textContent! what is the difference? Thanks

Comment: btw this also works:
console.log(episodeList[i].getElementsByTagName("EpisodeName").childNodes[0].nodeValue);

so the think that make it work was the:
push getElementsByTagName("lastupdated")[0], what is the diference without the [0]? thanks

Comment: @MarcoMartins `getElementsByTagName()` is DOM NodeList ,`getElementsByTagName()[index]` is DOM Node.